# Adding custom fonts to the keyboard extension ios 8

Tags: iphone, keyboard, ios8

How can I add custom fonts to ios 8 Keyboard extenstion like this.Can anyone have a tutorial or example from which I can refer.Like this example  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fontkeyboard-for-ios-8-use/id914787397?mt=8

Answer (score 5):

1.In the above link they have the special characters as letters, Please refer below URL
http://fsymbols.com/letters/

2.In Your Extension,You have to maintain the two arrays one is with regular letter (A,B,C,D….)to show on your Keyboard

3.Second one is the Special character that you want to display in your target E.g..,(Ⓐ,Ⓑ,Ⓒ,Ⓓ..) (⒜,⒝,⒞,⒟….)

4.Use can directly copy the special characters from the above reference URL,and then you return the value of selected letter

5.If you want to give an options like the referred app,you need to maintain the array of those letters and return the value that you wanted to display for that selected letter.

Here is the keyboard button action,the insertText method used to insert your text to the target.
[image]
[image]

Please find my blog on how to creating third-party keyboards  :[Here's a link](http://blog.mastersoftwaresolutions.com/ios-8-third-party-keyboards-using-app-extension/)

Please find my sample project on github :  [Simple Custom Keyboard Sample](https://github.com/mastersoftwaresolutions/Simple-Custom-keyboard-ios)

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but incase new people need the answer I will add mine. Gagan's answer (above) is quite elaborate and +1 for the github code; however, to my understanding the question is how to add font to custom keyboard, which could mean more than adding special characters to the keyboard keys (Gagan's answer), for example adding letters of languages not supported by apple.

In any case, to add a custom font to iOS keyboard extension, do the following steps:

> Step 1. Drag/Add your ttf font to the Keyboard extension folder
>   (NOT to the host app) of your project in xcode.
>   
> Step 2. While importing make sure to check "Copy items if needed" and finish.
>   
> Step 3. Select Info.plist under Supporting Files section of the Keyboard extension folder
>   
> Step 4. At the end of the list add a string array
>   called "Fonts provided by the Application" xcode will autocomplete it
>   for you.
>   
> Step 5. Extend the newly added array and add the name of your
>   font/fonts eg. "Example.ttf"
>   
> Step 6. Now to make sure the font is copied to the final binary app, go to project properties and in the Targets section select the keyboard extension, then in the "Build Phases" tab and the "Copy Bundle Resources" subsection add/link the custom font.

That should get you a custom font in your keyboard extension!

Notice that in the steps the Keyboard extension is mentioned repeatedly on purpose, because thats the catching point when adding custom font to the extension compared to adding font to normal applications and it should not be confused with host app of the extension. iOS Custom Keyboard project in xcode usually comprises a host app which is pretty much a normal iOS app and the actual keyboard extension, both are displayed as folders in the Project Navigator.

If the custom font is needed to be used in the host app, then the steps are similar, only then make sure the destination is the host app folder and once again select the host app Target in the project properties when adding to the Bundle resources.